# mvc3 html.actionlink unable to render partial view using $.ajax()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Just entered into mvc world and facing some strange problem while rendering
partail view using jquery.

I am using mvc3 and this is what i h've done so far:

anchor tag:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click-Me", null, null, null, new { onclick = "javascript:FillData();",id=2 })
```

div tag:

```
<div id="FillRecords"></div>
```

function:

```
    <script>

    function FillData() {

       var val1 = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({

        url: "/Dummy/Edit",
        datatype: "html",
        type:"Post",
          data:{id:val1.toString()},
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function (mydata) {
            $("#FillRecords").empty().append(mydata);
        },

        error: function (errorStatus,errorType,error) {
            alert(error);
        }

    });
}

</script>
```

I just want to render "Edit" partial view in "DummyController" when i click
the anchor tag. Also if i use simple anchor tag instead of html.actionlink
this worrks fine.

Does anyone know how to do it with actionlink?
Surely, I am missing something silly or is this even possible?

Please don't suggest me using Ajax.Actionlink because
that also works fine but I want to know why its failing with html.actionlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with little tweak here and there and i got my solution. To render my partial view
using html.action, i simply change the url of anchor tag to "#" because using firebug i can see it works. So for anybody who are facing problem for rendering partial view using Html.actionlink simply change the url to "#" of the anchor tag generated.

This is what i did:

anchor tag:

```
       <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Dummy")" id="clickme">ClickMe</a>
```

div tag:

```
      <div id="filldata"></div>
```

function:

```
      <script>

$("#clickme").click(function () {

    $(this).attr("href", "#");

    $.ajax({

        url: "/Dummy/Edit",
        success: function (mydata) {

            $("#filldata").empty().append(mydata);

        },
        error: function (error) {

            alert(error);

        }

    });

});

</script>
```

Althogh I solved my problem of rendering partial view but still wonder why changing url to
"#" works(may it no longer has url to navigate to....)

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLink is nothing more than a utility class that checks the routes configured in the app, and prints a link tag, with the URL that corresponds to that particular action/controller/params.

In simpler words: there is no magic behind it, you could as well write

```
<a href="@Url.Action(...)">Text</a>
```

Or directly write

```
<a href="/Controller/Action/id">Text</a>
```

The main advantage of using Url.Action, or Html.ActionLink, is that if you change the routes in your app, you won't have to worry about the links in your pages.

That means that, for what you want, there's no point in using Html.ActionLink, and you should just write

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Click-Me</a>
```

And add a jQuery event to the link. If using a recent version of jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function() {
    $.ajax(...);
});
```

The great thing about MVC.Net is that you are working directly with HTML/JS/CSS. The helper methods are there, literally, to help you. But in the end, they just write HTML, there's nothing else behind them, and their use is recomended, but not required.

Comment: if i also need to pass certain values to controller then how will i do that??consider a situation of editing records where each html.actionlink has some values(may be records id) associated to it as routes values and we need to fill some partial view using this id and at the end render this to some view

Comment: It depends in what you want to do. You are just calling a URL in your $.ajax call, but you could do a $('form').serialize(), and send all the fields in the form to the server. Another option would be to create a link using the @Url.Action helper, capture the event as in my example, and with $(this).attr('href') get the value of the URL you want to POST to...

Comment: thanks salgiza for your reply...........i also made some changes in my code to pass data to filldata function but iam still not able to render my partial view to the corressponding div.....could u pls check that.....am i still missing something??